# Browser Bug showing time text on input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am dealing with the following puzzle and I cannot understand why it is happening.

I have the following [I believe to be] equivalent pieces of javascript code, but one does not work as expected (notice the Console.Log):

Updates the UI a single time, then unexpectantly stops updating : http://jsfiddle.net/silentwarrior/1m0v6oj1/

```
    jQuery(function () {
    var isWorking = true;
    if (isWorking) {
        var timeEnd = 1431220406000; // generated from php
        var timeNow = 1431210557000; // generated from php
        var counter = 1;
        var t = "";
        setInterval(function () {
            try {
                var c = timeEnd - timeNow - counter;
                console.log(c);
                var d = new Date(c);
                if (c <= 1) {
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                    return;
                }
                t = "";
                if (d.getHours() > 0) {
                    t += d.getHours() + "h ";
                }
                if (d.getMinutes() > 0) {
                    t += d.getMinutes() + "m ";
                }
                t += d.getSeconds();
                jQuery("#factory_start_prod").val("Working ... " + t + "s left");
                counter = counter + 1;
            } catch (e) {

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
   });
```

Updates the UI constantly as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/silentwarrior/n3gkum2e/

```
jQuery(function () {
    var isWorking = true;
    if (isWorking) {
        var timeEnd = 1431220406000;
        var timeNow = 1431210557000;
        var counter = 1;
        var t = "";
        setInterval(function () {
            try {
                var c = timeEnd - Date.now();
                console.log(c);
                var d = new Date(c);
                if (c <= 1) {
                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
                    return;
                }
                t = "";
                if (d.getHours() > 0) {
                    t += d.getHours() + "h ";
                }
                if (d.getMinutes() > 0) {
                    t += d.getMinutes() + "m ";
                }
                t += d.getSeconds();
                jQuery("#factory_start_prod").val("Working ... " + t + "s left");
                counter = counter + 1;
            } catch (e) {

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

The only difference from each other is that, the one that works uses Date.now() to get the current timestamp, while the other one uses a pre-built time stamp.

Why would one example update the text in the input correctly while the other wouldn't?

PS: it is important to me to use generated timestamps instead of Date.now() in order to not depend on the users system when calculating the time left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is working, however with each iteration you are only subtracting `1` from the timestamp value, which is equivalent to `1ms`. Hence the value never appears to change unless you wait a *really* long time. You need to increment the `counter` by `1000` on each iteration for a second to be counted:

```
counter = counter + 1000;
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/1m0v6oj1/1/)

Comment: E.g., `Date.now()` sees the 1000ms delay on the interval, but the constant value in `timeNow` does not. Nice one.

Comment: Thank you. I was working with times in php, that uses timestamps of seconds instead of milliseconds that javascript does, and correcting them only once, while not in the counter, thats why I got confused.

Comment: @SilentWarrior: Note (re your P.S.) that you're still relying on the user's system when determining the time left. `setInterval` won't necessarily fire exactly when you tell it to; in fact, it can be very far off the specific time. (Example: If the user opens the console and types `alert("x")` and then waits, that will prevent the timer from firing.) Using `Date.now` might well be **more**, rather than less, reliable than `counter`. In any case, if it actually matters, then you need to use the server for that. You can't trust anything on the client.

Comment: You are right. However, the actual amount that will show (the first time) will be more accurate on the example where the timestamps are generated server side. I could, if I wanted better accuracy, use Date.now() to see if an actual full second has passed before messing with the counter, thus, giving correct seconds passed as time went on. But since the page will be refreshed fairly quickly, with actions and other things, the actual time wont go far off the 1 second mark.